# Some linked images not working in HTML

Tags: php, html

I have PHP code that generates HTML code which makes a grid of images. The images are taken from links that are generated for each new image, I also add 133x100 at the end of the image link to resize it on the page. My problem is that a seemingly random selection of images won't display, and I just get a broken image symbol. For example:

[This](http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/fWFc82js0fmoRAP-qOIPu5THSWqfSmTELLqcUywGkijVjZYMUrsm1j-9xgEObwgfEh_nvjlWhNzZCveCDfIBj98xqodQ2CZknz56P7fiDz9-TQXJVfdSXfgF9gT5DBg-4cBrQJnv8eMDKgnutIGTZeEpYt8dH5LTU_ePNwj-uE9s1aZVepTb9Czu33zpJC5UDL2Z8FjG/62fx62f%20.%20/133x100) is a link to an image that is generated on my page and is displayed.

[This](http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/fWFc82js0fmoRAP-qOIPu5THSWqfSmTELLqcUywGkijVjZYMUrsm1j-9xgEObwgfEh_nvjlWhNzZCveCDfIBj98xqodQ2CZknz59PfWwIzJxdwr9AK1hX_oq5A3-NiE-7cRoR-i6_rwOPRK7ttOQO7EoYt9KGMbTUv6GYg79uBg_gKJUe5CMpiO6jyrtaGwMUhTj5Ctaz55942IR%20.%20/133x100) is a link to an image that will not be displayed.

I am only allowed to post 2 links, but removing the `%20.%20/133x100` from the end of the last link will show what the picture should be.

Here is the part of the code for the image source:

```
 function display_images(){
    //This cycles through each image and displays it as HTML
    while($row = $item->fetch()){
       Echo "`<img src= '$link[Image_Link] . /133x100' />`"
    }
 }
```

It is then called here  in a class which puts the images in a grid:

```
<ul class="rig columns-4">
   <?php
       display_images();
   ?>
</ul>
```

Seemingly about every 2/20 images won't work, and seeing all the links are in the same format, I don't understand why they won't work, and it just seems random.

EDIT: I have noticed that the links that work have `62fx62f` at the end of them before the added `%20.%20/133x100`. If I add it to the raw link in the right place, it makes the image work. But using that generated link, the image still won't load on the page. So using a link with a working image will not work on the page. (This is the same with the raw link without `%20.%20/133x100`, that links to an image but also won't work on the website)

Comment: Can you please post the rest of the relevant code?

Comment: @BenPearlKahan What else are you suggesting I need to post? The only problem is the image's source. The rest of my code, the PHP and HTML work fine, and I don't see how it any other parts of the code could affect this pinpointed problem. There would be far too much code to post all of what is done to generate the HTML, the style sheets etc. If you had something specific in mind, please tell me, otherwise I don't know what else I could post to help.

Comment: Well your code for the image source is a mix of HTML and PHP, could you perhaps show us the rest of the code surrounding that command?

Comment: @BenPearlKahan I just added some more of what could be relevant, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

When visiting the links, the urls look like this:

```
http://www.example.com/image/randomcharacters%20.%20/133x100
```

The links work without the `%20.%20` at the right dimensions, like so:

```
http://www.example.com/image/randomcharacters/133x100
```

This leads me to believe that it may work if you try using the following for the image source instead:

```
<img src= '$link[Image_Link]/133x100' />
```

The full code would look like this, for the `while` function:

```
while($row = $item->fetch()){
    echo "<img src= '" . $link['Image_Link'] . "/133x100' />";
}
```

Comment: I see where you are coming from, that it won't work because of the ".", though, testing this code generates a link like [this](http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/fWFc82js0fmoRAP-qOIPu5THSWqfSmTELLqcUywGkijVjZYMUrsm1j-9xgEObwgfEh_nvjlWhNzZCveCDfIBj98xqodQ2CZknz59PfWwIzJxdwr9AK1hX_oq5A3-NiE-7cRoR-i6_rwOPRK7ttOQO7EoYt9KGMbTUv6GYg79uBg_gKJUe5CMpiO6jyrtaGwMUhTj5Ctaz55942IR/133x100). So as you can see, the image work, but it still won't show up on the grid... also, it doesn't seem to change the dimensions of the images.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of steamcommunity much but from the looks of it, i think you should try this.

Instead of putting

> . /133x100

Use

> /133fx100f

So your URLs would be

```
while($row = $item->fetch()){
    echo "<img src= '" . $link['Image_Link'] . "/133fx100f' />";
}
```

Just did some trial and error and found out. No explanations for this though!!

Comment: Sorry it took my a while to reply, I've been scouring to see if my code had any other errors. Using your solution still doesn't make it work. :\ any other ideas?

Comment: Have you tried checking this: [link](http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/fWFc82js0fmoRAP-qOIPu5THSWqfSmTELLqcUywGkijVjZYMUrsm1j-9xgEObwgfEh_nvjlWhNzZCveCDfIBj98xqodQ2CZknz59PfWwIzJxdwr9AK1hX_oq5A3-NiE-7cRoR-i6_rwOPRK7ttOQO7EoYt9KGMbTUv6GYg79uBg_gKJUe5CMpiO6jyrtaGwMUhTj5Ctaz55942IR/133fx100f). The original is this [link](http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/fWFc82js0fmoRAP-qOIPu5THSWqfSmTELLqcUywGkijVjZYMUrsm1j-9xgEObwgfEh_nvjlWhNzZCveCDfIBj98xqodQ2CZknz59PfWwIzJxdwr9AK1hX_oq5A3-NiE-7cRoR-i6_rwOPRK7ttOQO7EoYt9KGMbTUv6GYg79uBg_gKJUe5CMpiO6jyrtaGwMUhTj5Ctaz55942IR).

Comment: Yes, I can't get it to work using the solution you said though, and I can't get just that link to load. When I use your solution, all of the images go small again. Also, when I inspect-source of the broken image, I get the link you just posted, but it still won't load...

Comment: Can you post the HTML that is generated?